# colordialog conversion to number rather than string

Tags: vb.net

colordialog1.color will yield   "Color [A=255, R=95, G=33, B=222]", but i would like to return an integer like 2349821 instead. how is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
colorDialog1.Color.ToArgb()
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to BlueMonkMN's answer

If you need the Alpha byte:

```
colorDialog1.Color.ToArgb()
```

If you don't want the Alpha byte:

```
colorDialog1.Color.ToArgb() And &H00ffffff
```